# Laravel Route [front.profiles.store] not defined

Tags: laravel, view, controller, routes

Here is my function in ProfilesController ===> note that this controller is under /front folder :
    public function store()
    {
       bla bla ...
    }

and in the view :
    {{ Form::open(array('route' => 'front.profiles.store', 'files' => true)) }}

and route :
Route::resource('inscription',              'App\Controllers\Front\ProfilesController@create');

i'm using namesapces well but i dont know why it gives me this error.

Thanks :)

Comment: where is the named route front.profiles.store ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run the below command at your project's path.

```
composer dump-autoload
```

You may need to add the namespace to composer.json, under the autoload object:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "Front": "app/controllers/front"
    }
```

After that, execute again the command.